# How to strip the decimal point from a float in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, stripe-payments

I want to strip the decimal point from the price before sending the price to the form/stripe. Is there a different method I can use to go about doing this?

In my product.rb model I have:

```
def monetize_amount
    self.price.to_s.delete(".").to_f
end
```

In the charges_controller I have:

```
def create
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    # Amount in cents
  **@amount = @product.monetize_amount**

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
   :email => 'example@stripe.com',
   :card  => params[:stripeToken]
  )

  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
   :customer    => customer.id,
   :amount      => @amount,
   :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
   :currency    => 'usd'
  )

 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
 flash[:error] = e.message
 redirect_to charges_path
end
```

Comment: One way could be to multiply the number by 100 and say .to_i when inserting it in DB, so that if your column is type integer then the decimals wouldn't be stripped off, then while retrieving divide the final result by 100, and if you don't care about the something after the decimal just do a .to_i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do like argentum47 said.  Convert it to an integer value in cents.

```
class Product < AR::Base
  def price_in_cents
    (price * 100).to_i
  end
end
```

Then later on you can do:

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
   :customer    => customer.id,
   :amount      => @product.price_in_cents,
   #…
```